# jQuery Background Image Transition How To?

Tags: jquery, image, background, background-image, fade

I'm trying to create a homepage with a changing background. Right now, I have it set so that the body itself holds the background image, and I simply want one image to fade to the next and then cycle through to the beginning.

My first issue: it isn't working. Period.
My second issue: if it did work, it would probably instantly transition to the next one before delaying on the interval...how can I prevent this?

Following is my code, which is found at the bottom of the  tags on the html document:

```
$(window).load(function() {
           var current_scene = 0;
           setInterval(function() {
               if (current_scene == 0) {
                   var current_scene = 1;
                   $(body).animate({
                       backgroundImage: 'url(...)'
                   },400);
               } else if (current_scene == 1) {
                   var current_scene = 2;
                   $(body).animate({
                       backgroundImage: 'url(...)'
                   },400);
               } else {
                   var current_scene = 0;
                   $(body).animate({
                       backgroundImage: 'url(...)'
                   },400);
               }
           }, 3000);
       });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u cant animate body's backgorund-image with js, and change body selector to $("body")

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
                var current_scene = 0;
                setInterval(function() {
                    startAnimation();
                }, 3000);

                function startAnimation() {
                    if (current_scene == 0) {
                        current_scene = 1;
                        $("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(1.png)' });
                    } else if (current_scene == 1) {
                        current_scene = 0;
                        $("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(2.png)' });
                    }
                }
            });
```

or try this clean code

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            var img_array = ['1.png', '2.png'];
            var indexOfImage = 0;
            var interval = 3000;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + img_array[indexOfImage++ % img_array.length] + ')');
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
            }, interval);
        });
```

add some style to body

```
body {
    background-image: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.6s ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

Declared variable globally and fixed quotes for the selector $("body")

```
var current_scene = 0;
    $(window).load(function() {

           setInterval(function() {
               if (current_scene == 0) {

                   current_scene = 1;

                   $("body").animate({

                       backgroundImage: 'url("someimagename.png")'

                   },400);

               } else if (current_scene == 1) {

                   current_scene = 2;

                   $("body").animate({

                       backgroundImage: 'url("someimagename2.png")'

                   },400);

               } else {

                   current_scene = 0;

                   $("body").animate({

                       backgroundImage: 'url("someimagename3.png")'

                   },400);

               }
           }, 3000);

       });
```